# Infinite scroll like behaviour on loop

Tags: java, android, performance

I have in my android app a code snippet that uses a loop for making/drawing rectangles.

```
int total_rect = 2000;//This nr should not have to be here.
 float rect_positions[][] = new float[total_rect][2];

for(int i =0;i<total_rect;i++){
          rect_positions[i][0] = 600 + i*300 ;
          rect_positions[i][1] =  rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f;
    }
```

They appear every 300 DP when the game scrolls.

The reason is that i wanted it to be endless of rectangles so i dont want to set a specific nr to it.

But i have(?) to make an initial nr to run the loop. (not really sure about this...)

So what i want to know is:

Is there any other(better) way to do this because now i get REALLY low fps and it is lagging like h3ll due to all the calculations for the loop.

Maybe something in the lines of :

```
int total_rect = 5;
when i>4 run loop again //This is what i dont know how to code...
```

That should work i think.

Or maybe something like

```
when rect_positions>last_rectposition + 1500 run loop again //This is the one i think would be the best alternative because that would meen that the further you get the more loops it will be.
```

Or is it anyone that have a different idea?

Comment: you can scroll by Activity or User interface UI

Comment: Yes i know how to scroll but i need to add more rectangles as i move/scroll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705510/android-scrollview-cant-be-created-programmatically

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: Ok. Thanx for your effort. But i have my scrollview in order. Everything with that works. I want to load more rectangles as more that i scroll. Now i add rectangles with my loop(first code base in q) but i dont want to set 2000 (or higher) because when i add a big nr there (like 2000) i get lagging. so that is why i need the loop to add more rect as far as i go/scroll

Comment: @Rechard nice great u have dun by these link ....u can vote up

Comment: No these links did not help me at all. I already have my scroll in order....  Please read my question again